# How to be distinct on a name column and only display the highest ts_rank for that column PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I posted a question on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074943/how-to-get-distinct-value-on-one-coulmn-for-a-ts-rank-in-postgres) but then I realized I am wanting more than just what I was asking.

I actually need to be DISTINCT on the `name` column by its highest `ts_rank`, So my code is,

```
SELECT name
    ,ts_rank(to_tsvector(name), query) + ts_rank(to_tsvector(content), query2) AS rank
FROM users
INNER JOIN microposts ON users.id = microposts.user_id
    ,plainto_tsquery('re') query
    ,plainto_tsquery('comics') query2
WHERE users.name @@ query
OR microposts.content @@ query2
ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

Gives

```
╔════════════════╤═════════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════╗
║ name           │ content                                 │ rank      ║
╠════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════╣
║ Dawson Kreiger │ dc comics dc comics dc comics dc comics │ 0.0919062 ║
╟────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ Kaylin Green   │ dc comics dc comics dc comics           │ 0.0889769 ║
╟────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ Dawson Kreiger │ dc comics dc comics                     │ 0.0827456 ║
╟────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ Kaylin Green   │ dc comics                               │ 0.0759909 ║
╟────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ Dawson Kreiger │ I went to the beach dc comics           │ 0.0607927 ║
╟────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ Dawson Kreiger │ I went to the beach dc comics           │ 0.0607927 ║
╟────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ Kaylin Green   │ I went to the beach dc comics           │ 0.0607927 ║
╟────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ Kaylin Green   │ I went to the beach dc comics           │ 0.0607927 ║
╚════════════════╧═════════════════════════════════════════╧═══════════╝
```

So I need the output to be this,

```
╔════════════════╤═════════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════╗
║ name           │ content                                 │ rank      ║
╠════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════╣
║ Dawson Kreiger │ dc comics dc comics dc comics dc comics │ 0.0919062 ║
╟────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────╢
║ Kaylin Green   │ dc comics dc comics dc comics           │ 0.0889769 ║
╚════════════════╧═════════════════════════════════════════╧═══════════╝
```

So I need to select a record that is distinct by name and has the highest `rank`. But how will the code know how to select the distinct user with the highest ts_rank?

**EDIT**

For instance if I do this

```
SELECT name
    , ts_rank(to_tsvector(name), query) + ts_rank(to_tsvector(content), query2) AS rank 
FROM
    (
     SELECT DISTINCT name FROM users WHERE rank = MAX(rank)
     ) 
INNER JOIN microposts ON users.id=microposts.user_id
    , plainto_tsquery('re') query
    ,plainto_tsquery('comics') query2 
WHERE users.name @@ query 
OR microposts.content @@ query2 
ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

I get `error: column "rank" does not exist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a `GROUP BY`  with a `MAX`.

```
SELECT name
    ,MAX(ts_rank(to_tsvector(name), query) + ts_rank(to_tsvector(content), query2)) AS rank
FROM users
INNER JOIN microposts ON users.id = microposts.user_id
    ,plainto_tsquery('re') query
    ,plainto_tsquery('comics') query2
WHERE users.name @@ query
OR microposts.content @@ query2
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY rank DESC;
```

Comment: Daym, I went down that road I am fairly sure but I must have had something wrong. Thanks again for that!

Comment: @LeeEather : You're welcome. I think you may delete your previous question.