# Postgresql: Join on highest ts_rank

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

Let's say I have two tables, `apartments` and `geonames`.
The former has a column `location`, which contains freely-typed data.
The latter has a generated column `search_vector`, created by applying `to_tsvector` to some of its other columns.

If I run a join query like this, I'll get multiple matches for many columns from the `apartments` table.

```sql
SELECT * FROM
apartments JOIN geonames ON search_vector @@ phraseto_tsquery('english', location)
```

However, I'm just interested in the coordinates of the closest match between the `location` and `search_vector` columns.
I know I can include a `ts_rank` function in this statement, and then use a window function to get the highest-ranking match, but I'm wondering if there is a less verbose, and more efficient way to do this.
An example of such a query would be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts_rank DESC) proximity_rank
    FROM (
        SELECT id, "location", link, "name", latitude, longitude, ts_rank(g.search_vector, phraseto_tsquery('english', re."location"))
        FROM apartments re JOIN geonames g ON g.search_vector @@ phraseto_tsquery('english', re."location")
    ) sq
) sq2
WHERE proximity_rank = 1
```

My question is closely related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083702/how-to-be-distinct-on-a-name-column-and-only-display-the-highest-ts-rank-for-tha), but but since that one is a bit old, I'm wondering if there are any new constructs that Postgresql supports.
After some testing, I've realized that the `@@` operator, while fast, is pretty limited because it imposes a constraint on the token ordering - another reason why I need an efficient join on the ts_rank.

Comment: *I know I can include a ts_rank function in this statement, and then use a window function to get the highest-ranking match*: please show us this query, so we can suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres, this might be a good spot for `distinct on`, which is there exactly to shorten this type of top-1-per-group query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (re.id)
    re.id, re.location,
    g.link, g.name, g.latitude, g.longitude, 
    ts_rank(g.search_vector, phraseto_tsquery('english', re.location)) rn
FROM apartments re 
JOIN geonames g 
    ON g.search_vector @@ phraseto_tsquery('english', re.location)
ORDER BY re.id, rn DESC
```

An alternative would be a lateral join:

```
SELECT 
    re.id, re.location,
    g.link, g.name, g.latitude, g.longitude, g.rn
FROM apartments re 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT g.*,
        ts_rank(g.search_vector, phraseto_tsquery('english', re.location)) rn
    FROM geonames g 
    WHERE g.search_vector @@ phraseto_tsquery('english', re.location)
    ORDER BY rn DESC
    LIMIT 1
) g       
ORDER BY re.id
```

Note that it is a good practice to qualify columns with the table they belong to. I attempted to apply it.